# Need help in importing data from pdfplumber to .csv file

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, tabula, python-pdfreader

## I used pdfplumber to extract text from pdfs but when I tried to import the data using to_csv throwing #me an error. Need help in importing the data to .csv

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

pdf = pdfplumber.open('C:/Users/Desktop/Mydata.pdf')
page = pdf.pages[1-76]
text = page.extract_text()
text
print(text)



text2 = pd.DataFrame([text])

text2.to_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\MyPDFData\\converted_text.csv")
```

## Not getting the data in the imported file just got an empty file

Comment: what `print(text2)` is showing?

Comment: You are creating the dataframe with one element in this line `text2 = pd.DataFrame(['tex1'])` and exporting it to csv. Are you sure there is no type in the code.?

Comment: I edited the code..and print(text2) is showing this

Comment: 0
0    text     this is want it is showing when I printed text2

Comment: @MurthyP - Still in this edited code you are creating a dataframe with single element only and exporting it yo csv. You are not exporting the data extracted from pdf to csv. `text2` here is dataframe with single element that is string 'text'

Comment: got it...I changed the code but still not getting the output...getting an empty file with header

Answer (score 0):

You may not need pandas to do it. 
Just open the CSV engine first :

```
with open(your_csv_file_name, mode='w', newline='') as export_csv:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(export_csv, escapechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        csv_writer.writerow(text)
```

There is an excellent page to understand CSV exportation:

https://realpython.com/python-csv/?fireglass_rsn=true